# Relay command using injected data service not invoked

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, lambda, mvvm-light, relaycommand

When I use an injected instance of a data service in the lambda statement that defines a relay command handler, the handler is never invoked (it is associated with a button). When I declare an instance of the data service within the lambda, it works fine. Any ideas?

Edited: 
Created the class variable _dataService and initialized it in the view model constructor. Use the class variable within the relay command handler and all works.

```
    private IDataService _dataService;
    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
        Batches = new ObservableCollection<Batch>();

        #region RefreshCommand
        RefreshCommand = new RelayCommand(
            () =>
            {
                var t1 = Task<ObservableCollection<Batch>>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    // WHEN I UNCOMMENT AND COMMENT OUT BELOW, WORKS FINE.
                    //DataService test = new DataService();
                    //ObservableCollection<Batch> batches = test.GetBatchesToProcess();

                    //
                    // THIS NOW WORKS.
                    return _dataService.GetBatchesToProcess();
                });
                try
                {
                    t1.Wait();
                }
                catch (AggregateException ae)
                {
                    foreach (var e in ae.InnerExceptions)
                    {
                        if (e is SqlException)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Sql Exception: " + e.Message);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Unexpected error: " + e.Message);
                        }
                    }
                    return;
                }
                Batches = t1.Result;
            }
        );
        #endregion  
    }
```

Comment: How do you know it is not being invoked?

Comment: With breakpoints. The working version hit a breakpoint on t1.Wait(); the non-working version did not.

Comment: If you found a solution you should post the solution as an answer and leave the question alone as future users will not realize what the problem was or what the solution was.

Answer (score 0):

Using the dataService parameter to the MainViewModel constructor did not work within the relay command handler. Using a private class variable (_dataService) that is initialized within the constructor solved the dilemma.